# How do I dynamicly change the css font size using an input in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to re-size the font size of one of my divs in jquery using an input.
Ideally, the number put inside the input box would be added on to the existing font size but so far my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Here is what I have so far but it does not seem to be working:

**HTML**

```
<div class="resizeable" style="font-size: 30px;">test</div>
<input type="text" name="size" class="size" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.size').keyup(function() {
        var currentFontSize = $('this').css('font-size');
        var input = $(this).val(); // grab the input value
        var newsize = input + currentFontSize;
        console.log(size);

        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        {
            // replace css value on live preview 
            $('.resizeable').css('font-size', newsize);  
        } 
    }); 
});
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/eqE2R/36/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eqE2R/42/)**

You forgot to add `px` to the value. You must also parse the values to the int

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentFontSize = $('.resizeable').css('font-size');
    $('.size').keyup(function() {
        var input = $(this).val(); // grab the input value
        var newsize = parseInt(input) + parseInt(currentFontSize);

        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        {
            // replace css value on live preview 
            $('.resizeable').css('font-size', newsize + 'px');  
        } 
    }); 
});
```

**EDIT**:
I moved the `currentFontSize` variable deifnition outside the `keyup` function, so it will be declared only once at the begining.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. The only problem now is that it is always adding to the size and won't downsize. Ex: change from 10 to 5 will make it 15.

Comment: That's right. You added `currentFontSize` to the `newsize`. You want it to be back `30px` when the input is empty?

Comment: Ideally, I want it to be able to reduce in size if the new value is greater than the last value but I want to avoid hard coding the original size in the jquery.

Comment: Thanks! I am still learning JQuery. Hopefully I will get the hang of it soon :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `px` value and use `parseInt()` for addition:

```
$('.size').keyup(function() {
    var currentFontSize = $('.resizeable').css('font-size');
    var input = $(this).val(); // grab the input value
       alert(currentFontSize)
    var newsize =parseInt(input,10) + parseInt(currentFontSize,10);
    console.log(newsize);

    if ($(this).val().length > 0)
    {
        // replace css value on live preview 
        $('.resizeable').css('font-size', newsize + 'px');  
    } 
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqE2R/40/)